# Local Notification to be shown as Alert Type

Tags: iphone, notifications, alert, uilocalnotification

I am using local notifications in my application. I want to show local notifications as Alert Type on iphone devices while it is displaying as Banner Type. I have also set the alert type of local notification that is not contains the null value. Please Suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change the way a Notification is presented by code, iOS handles the displaying the notifications.

Only the user can set the way a notification is presented from the settings app.

Comment: Is there not any API that change it as default way to represent local notification as Alert Type?

Comment: I guess i wasn't clear, no you can not change the way a notification is presented. Like my answer said, "You can't change the way Notifications is presented by code".